# Admob wont display with webview

Tags: android, webview, admob

I cant get my admob ads to display.. I think the problem is with the setContentView(web), but I cant figure out how to fix it.  I think its because i switch to a different layout? I tried searching but couldnt find a solution

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;
private AdView adView;

private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;  
 private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE=1;  

 @Override  
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                    Intent intent) {  
  if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
  {  
   if (null == mUploadMessage) return;  
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null  
                    : intent.getData();  
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);  
            mUploadMessage = null;  
  }
  }  

/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
    //Parse.initialize(this, "", ""); 
    //ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    //testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    //testObject.saveInBackground();
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);


    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ""); 

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
  adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
  adRequest.addTestDevice("");    

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    //progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    web = new WebView(this);  
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://.com"); 
    web.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()  
    {  
           //The undocumented magic method override  
           //Eclipse will swear at you if you try to put @Override here  
        // For Android 3.0+
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {  
            File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Modeling Hawaii");
           // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
           if (! imageStorageDir.exists()){
               imageStorageDir.mkdirs();                  
           }
           File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");  
           Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);  

           final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
           final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
           final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
           for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
               final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
               final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
               intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
               intent.setPackage(packageName);
               intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
               cameraIntents.add(intent);
           }

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
            i.setType("image/*");  
            MainMenu.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i,"File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);  

           }

        // For Android 3.0+
           public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
           mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
           i.setType("*/*");
           MainMenu.this.startActivityForResult(
           Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
           FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
           }

        //For Android 4.1
           public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
               mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
               i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
               i.setType("image/*");  
               MainMenu.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MainMenu.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

           }

    });  


    setContentView(web);  






}

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

           // progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}   
  //flipscreen not loading again
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    //To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
     if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
         web.goBack();
         return true;
     }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  if (adView != null) {
    adView.destroy();
  }
  super.onDestroy();
}


//    public void onBackPressed() 
//    {
//        if(mWebView.canGoBack())
//            mWebView.goBack();
//        else{
//            Intent start = new Intent(MainMenu.this,MainMenu.class);
//        startActivity(start);
//        finish();    }}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate your `WebView` in a another ViewGroup and put `AdView` in it. then you can change contentView with your `AdView`. Actually, when you set your activity's contentView in to a web view or to  another single `View`  it will show only the view. therefore, you better set your content view to a `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout` and put your views in it.

i hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Ercan, Im still a lil confused I moved my webview into lineaLayout1 in my xml tried to call  setContentView(linearlayout1)?

Comment: I get the following error in my logcat "you must call removeView() on the childs parent first

Comment: it is because you added that view in another ViewGroup before. Create a new AdView and put it instead of the old one. or you can remove the adview from it parent by removeView(view) method.(it is the layout.removeChild(adview)  in your case)

Comment: I deleted "setContentView(web);" and added "layout.addView(web);" It works now but when it loads the activity the view is screwed for a bit then displays normally

Comment: Use xml layout for this. Adding views programmatically is not wrong. But it is confusing and hard for visual design of user interface.You can put any view in any ViewGroup in xml by simple adding as child between their tags.